# Conversion of a statement in formal language

Tags: coq

(length l=?0)=false. It means at least one element is present in the list,it could be zero. I want to write that no element in the list is zero .I do not know how to write it formally.

Answer (score 0):

You know that `0` is not in the empty list `[]` and you know that if `l` doesn't contain `0` then adding any non-zero integer to it will still yield a list without `0`, in other words `x :: l` doesn't contain `0` (when `x <> 0`).
If you call `nozeroes l` this property on list `l`, do you see a way of defining it?

Comment: (length(h::h1::l)=?0)=false-> 
(h=?h1)=false->
(h=?0)=false->
Its means at least two elements present in the list which are not equal to each other and not equal to zero.In the presence of these coditions we can say one element is greater than other at least.

Comment: You don't have to talk about the `length` at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write that no element in the list is zero .

*"`0` is not in the list `l`"* is written `~ In 0 l.`